# How does the name you give your game affect its success?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I have been doing my third playthrough to find some answers to some of the questions on here, so have been leaving everything with its default name. For example;

- Game Engine #2
- Game #17
- etc...

During one of my latest game releases, I received the following from one of the magazine reviews;

[image]

[image]

Is this just a random message that I haven't seen before now? How does the name you give your game affect its success?

Comment: I would guess they just plug in common phrases seen in such reviews and that there is no correlation between the name of the game and its success.

Comment: Yeah but when I went through the process of naming my games, I never ever once saw this message through many hours of play, then once I stopped naming my games I got it two games in a row...

Comment: Can this question be answered? Isn't it purely speculation? I mean, if there is an answer to this question then wouldn't all developers follow it in order to maximize sales?

Comment: It could be that the developers of the game checked to see if the default name is used and if so then those messages are added.

Comment: This may seem sarcastic, but I promise its not. Did you produce a game called "the name"?

Comment: @CaesiumFarmer lol, no I didn't :P

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As the developer, I can give you a definitive answer:

Whether or not you give your game a custom name does **not** affect the value of the ratings.

However, if you simply leave the name as Game #X, it can cause some tongue-in-cheek responses from the reviewers who will refer to this fact. It doesn't change the value of the review, it just changes the text.

We just thought of it as a friendly poke to say that the game world *cares* about the name but we didn't want to actually penalize players for not naming their games.

Comment: Hi Patrick, many thanks for dropping by to fill us in on this - it's much appreciated!

Comment: Another good marker of quality is a game that I'm still playing occasionally two years after it came out. GDT certainly stood the test of time in that regard. :)